# How to download skyrim from steam and play on ubuntu

Tags: steam

I recently bought Skyrim on Steam and did not know that it can only be played on Windows. I was wondering how can I play Skyrim on my Ubuntu computer?

Comment: Use PlayOnLinux, please read this comprehensive guide, http://www.gamersonlinux.com/forum/threads/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim-guide.331/

Answer (score 18):

There is a project called PlayOnLinux that works to automatically setup many games devloped for Windows, to be played on Linux with minimal hassle.

You can get the program via the repositories using the command `sudo apt-get install playonlinux` or from the website [playonlinux.com](http://www.playonlinux.com/).

Once PoL is installed you can run the program. To install a game, click the button on the right-hand sidebar that says "Install a program". Once in that menu just use the search bar to find "The Elder Scrolls V : Skyrim", click to install. This will automatically download the version of WINE that is known to work with Skyrim as well as install Steam on the virtual drive, if you so select.

The installation *may* throw an error, but they usually provide you with information on how to fix it, commonly in the form of a link to a "How to fix problem X" type page. Just follow the prompts and it should work.

Alternatively, you can [download and install it from playonlinux.com](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/commentaires-1047.html).

Answer (score 3):

My comprehensive [guide to modding and installing Skyrim on linux wine](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/2110829-modding-skyrim-with-wine-playonlinux-in-linux-ubuntu/).

Answer (score -1):

You just have to download the [fresh version of Steam of Linux.](http://store.steampowered.com/about/?snr=1_4_4__11)

Just to let you know, before the release of Steam for Linux you would have to go through a non trivial process installing the Steam for windows version to Linux via [Wine](http://winehq.com).

EDIT: Since Skyrim is not yet available, you would have to install it using wine. You could take a look [here](http://www.steamgamesonlinux.com/skyrim-the-elder-scrolls-v/).

Comment: Skyrim isn't available on the Linux Steam Client right now, so he'll have to use the Wine/PlayOnLinux approach.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, you can clearly see what a hardcore gamer I am :)

Comment: I am sorry I must have miss spoke I have Stream for linux downloaded through the Ubuntu software center. However my issue is that when I goto download the game it says that it only works for Windows. Should I use wine to play the game or do they have an Ubuntu version that i am just missing?

Comment: As @Merri mentioned, yes, you would have to install onother copy of steam(the windows version) using wine and try playing Skyrim from there.